# How to get the attachment of an item attachment using microsoft graph api?

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I want to retrieve attachment which is inside a mail& this mail itself is an attachment of another mail.I am using microsoft graph api.I have used item attachment api which will extract the message but if the mail has an attachment.How to get the attachment of an attached email?

Answer (score 0):

When emails are attached to other emails, the name of the attachment is usually the subject name of the attached email. You could fire off another Microsoft Graph request with a filter clause specifying that name as the subject. You can then repeat this process to get to the inner attached email and so forth.